# UI-solution for iOS/Swift

Tags: usability, ios, image, workflow, data-tables

I hope that this kind of question is welcome here **If not, please excuse me !**

I have a TableViewController in iOS/Swift on top of the workflow:

[image]

In my setup, this controller is use to update/add rows:

> SetupViewController

[image]

When the image on the right is tapped, a collection-view is shown and you have to select a *new* image:

[image]

I hope you can give me hints on how to proceed (perhaps with some code-snippet)

**How can I "mark" the images in the SetupViewController** on the right, so that the user recognizes, that he/she should tap on image to select another one (i.e the question mark when adding a record) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some visual clue showing the icon can be changed. Maybe a little pencil or an arrow

[image: Using arrows]

[image: Using a edit icon]

Comment: Ohhh, that looks very fine and convincingly! Any tip from where to get the displayed arrow/pencil? ;-)

Comment: there's a lot of free services for icons, like https://www.iconfinder.com/. Just google it